# How to do sparse matrix (dgCMatrix) operation to save time?

Tags: r

I am processing linear regression involves a large sparse matrix. The processing time is very long if I compute with the matrix as regular matrix directly. I found I probably need to convert the matrix to "dgCMatrix" first, but I don't know how to compute with such "dgCMatrix" matrix.

For example,

```
M<-matrix(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0), nc=4) 
A<-c(1,2,3,4)
M<-as(M, "sparseMatrix")
str(M)
Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:4] 0 1 2 0
  ..@ p       : int [1:5] 0 0 1 3 4
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 3 4
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ x       : num [1:4] 1 1 1 1
  ..@ factors : list()
px<-as.integer(x@p + 1)
ix<-as.integer(x@i + 1)
x<-as.double(x@x)
```

Then I have no idea how to continue. How do I use so information to do matrix operations(e.g, multiplication like below, add, substract etc.) in a more efficient way using dgCMatrix sparse matrix info.

```
M%*%A
3 x 1 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
      [,1]
[1,]    6
[2,]    3
[3,]    3
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Is your matrix of independent variables sparse? If so, you can very efficiently perform a linear regression with the MatrixModels package:

```
MatrixModels:::lm.fit.sparse(M, A)
```

Answer (score 0):

dtm <- dtm[,colSums(dtm) > 15]
If you have a document matrix, you can reduce sparse by set up your number